# HDD shows up in BIOS but not in disk manager

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, laptop, ssd

I recently bought a Kingston A2000 ssd and installed it on my Asus N580G laptop, the laptop came with Intel Optane in the NVMe slot so I swapped it with the ssd. The laptop also came with a Toshiba HDD (1 TB, don't know the exact model), that's where my OS was before I formatted my laptop.

So I installed Windows 10 and just finished installing every driver and Windows Update, but my hdd is not recognized by disk manager and I'm left with only the 250 GB that my SSD has. The HDD is shown on my computer BIOS but not in Windows. What can I do to fix this? Thanks in advancement.

**Edit:** Because @harrymc asked, I will further explain what have I done with the drives:

- The HDD that is giving me problems was the main storage unit for my laptop for almost 2 years, I used it for collegue, work and games. Nothing really wild, just normal day to day use.
- Today I opened my laptop and had to remove the HDD from the built in SATA port so I could uncover the NVMe port. Then removed the Intel Optane that came with the laptop and inserted the M.2 SSD. After that I plugged back in the HDD.
- I installed Windows 10 in the SSD via a flash drive created with the Windows 10 Media Creation Tool. I deleted all the partitions that showed up in the installation window (I don't remember if the HDD showed up there). Then created the Windows 10 partitions automatically in the SSD.
- Started Windows 10 after it installed, first thing I did was installing NVidia Drivers and then just waited while everything was updating.

That's pretty much everything I did, hope that's helpful!

Comment: What *exactly* have you done with the disks, software and hardware? [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1629367/edit) your post and add all these details.

Comment: @harrymc just edited!

Answer (score 2):

From the badly-translated ASUS article
[Troubleshooting - Cannot find the hard disk or SSD after motherboard powers on](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1044083/):

> M.2_1 port is shared with SATA6G_1 port. Therefore ,when connecting
> the device to the two ports, SATA6G_1 port will be closed.
>
> At this time, the computer can only recognize M.2 SSD in M.2_1 port,
> and it can't recognize the hard disk in SATA6G_1.  If you need
> computer to recognize the hard disk in SATA6G_1，please connect Sata
> cable of SATA6G_1 port to other Sata port, such as SATA6G_3 or
> SATA6G_4

I assume that the HDD is connected to the same SATA6G_1 port to which was connected
before, which is now disabled because of the SSD.

Connecting the HDD to one of the other SATA ports should then enable it to work
correctly. Otherwise, there may have been some hardware damage.

Comment: Thanks! This is very informative. Seems like I'm gonna have to buy a new SATA cable!

Comment: Have you tried connecting with the old SATA cable, but to another internal SATA port?

Comment: There was no SATA cable. The HDD is connected directly into the port. I will buy a short SATA cable.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after a widows update. I eventually found that the solution was a missing SATA driver. Go to device manager, human interface devices,
IDE ATA/ATAPI controllers, AMD SATA controller, update driver. Browse my computers, locate and install manually. Let me pick from a list of drivers on this computer and chose standard SATA AHCI controller.

Hope this helps as I am down to my last tufts of hair out of frustration.